# C# how to get value from specific cell datagridview

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

i am working on C# and trying to save my datagridview to xml.

my code as follow :

```
writer.WriteStartElement("NamaBarang");
writer.WriteString(dgvCart.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString);
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

and the error occur at

```
 writer.WriteString(dgvCart.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString);
```

> Error 2   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteString(string)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\C#\Gridview\Gridview\Form1.cs 59  25  Gridview

and

> Error 3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'string'  C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\C#\Gridview\Gridview\Form1.cs 59  44  Gridview

i am previously a vb user so i am having a hard time in c#
please help.

Comment: By the way, this could be a lot easier if you make a DataTable, bond it to the DataGridView, then just call the WriteXml method of the DataTable

Comment: I will try that, after i get used to c#. for now, let me take this as a lesson :)

Comment: Ok, here's a quick run down how to do that: right click your project in the solution explorer, choose new item.. new dataset.. double click the dataset, right click the surface and choose new DataTable, right click the table and choose new column (repeatedly).. save when you're done and switch to your form editor.. open the data sources toolwindow (google for how).. drag the icon representing the DataTable you made out of datasourxes and drop it on the form.. you're done, other than a button to click to save (call yourdataset.writexml or yourdataset.yourtable.writexml)

Comment: It works because the grid that appears when you drop the DataTable onto thenform, is connected to a DataTable inside a dataset (that is also added to the form). When you edit the grid it creates and edits rows in the DataTable, then you just write to disk.  If you want the xml in a custom format you can use transforms, but in simple terms first, just call your table and columns what you want your xml records to look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youve forgotten to put empty brackets () after your ToString

VB isn't bothered about this but c# is- every time you want to call a method that has no arguments, you have to put empty brackets

```
//this is fine in VB
Dim x as String = y.ToString

//so is this
Dim x as String = y.ToString()

//in c# we insist on brackets when calling a method
string x = y.ToString();

//no brackets means "get the value of the property" 
int I = mystring.Length;
```

Seeing something that looks like a method name, without brackets, usually means it's a property rather than a method. It can occasionally mean that the method itself is being used as an argument - a way of passing a method around as a variable, but that's beyond the scope of what we're discussing here.. Read up on delegates if you're interested.

In short, if you want to call a method in c#, it absolutely must have brackets after the name, whether there are arguments or not

Also handy to remember  that when you see the error about "is a method group" it probably means you've tried to call a method but omitted the brackets.

C# is a struggle for VB people because it's essentially way more demanding that the syntax be absolutely right- you'll get used to it though, and it does help eventually!

Comment: thank you very much. Indeed, it's hard for me. because .tostring in vb does not need empty bracket.

Comment: Eventually you'll come to appreciate it; or suffer it :) - in c# I could tell you that a call to `mylist.Count` is a property and `mylist.Count()` is a method. In vb you can't, but then you can't make a method and a property have the same name in vb (and indeed, why would anyone do that?) - it is what it is, c# is case sensitive, demanding, precise ... it becomes natural eventually and I do think it helps make a person think more precisely, which is a good thing in programming